# Почему фонетика русского языка так похожа на язык эрзя и мокши?

Tags: фонетика

Когда слушаешь песни на эрзянском языке, то появляется ощущение что они поют на русском, но почему-то ничего не понятно. В разговорной речи точно также, чего не скажешь о "близких" украинском и белорусском языках.
[видео-1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57lWg1-Iam8),
[видео-2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OAALsCVaq8)

Answer (score 2):

Я не владею мордовскими, но предполагаю, что ваше восприятие чисто субъективно.
Фонетика *финно-угорских*  (в данном случае - *финно-волжских*) не может быть похожа на славянский по определению.
Например, сингармонизм гласных. Разве что-то похожее есть в русском?
(+)
Почитал вот тут: http://www.mordovia.info/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0
Все, что увидел похожего: оглушение звонких перед глухими.

Так что, или вы назвали "фонетикой" нечто иное, или действительно ошиблись.
А вообще песни - не лучший источник знаний о фонетике.

Answer (score 2):

Похожа, но не фонетика может, а говор. Как будто русским говором говорят. И оканье тоже. Видимо, русский язык испытал сильное влияние финно-угорских языков в плане произношения. Возможно, местные финно-угорские племена переняли русский язык, но произношение оставили своё.

Comment: Что такое "говор" в вашем употреблении?